# Post não envia as informações

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post

Preciso enviar algumas informações por POST para meu controlador, e ao mesmo tempo passar um parâmetro na URL. O Parâmetro da url eu consigo pegar tranquilo, o problema é que os parâmetros de POST não vão.

Estou utilizando essa função para gerar um form e enviar com as informações:

```
function paginacao(pagina,BASE_URL){
        var url = BASE_URL+"acompanhamento/Aluno/"+pagina;
        var hiddenForm = $("<form method='post' action='"+url+"'>"+
          "<input type='text' id='campoParam' value='"+$('#campo').val()+"'>"+
          "<input type='text' id='dataInicialAvaliacaoParam' value='"+$('#dataInicialAvaliacao').val()+"'>"+
          "<input type='text' id='dataFinalAvaliacaoParam' value='"+$('#dataFinalAvaliacao').val()+"'>"+
          "<input type='text' id='cursoAvaliacaoParam' value='"+$('#cursoAvaliacao').val()+"'>"+
          "<input type='text' id='paginaParam' value='"+$('#pagina').val()+"'>"+
          "<input type='submit' id='btnSubmitParam' value='"+$('#pagina').val()+"'>"+
          "</form>");
          $('body').append(hiddenForm);
          $('#btnSubmitParam').click();
          //hiddenForm.submit();
      }
```

Eu já verifiquei as variáveis dentro dos values e elas trazem o valor esperado. Mas quando tento dar uma `var_dump($_POST).` no controlador, recebo empty

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A váriável `pagina` que vai na URL(segunda linha) é o parâmetro que vai no get, o metodo está POST como deveria mesmo, mas mesmo assim o controlador não recebe

Se tiver faltado alguma informação, me avisem por favor!

OBS: Já tentei passar apenas os parâmetro POST sem a variável na url e o resultado foi o mesmo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa adicionar o atributo name nos campos de input eles são usados para referenciar após o formulário ser submitado.

Comment: Muito obrigado é exatamente isso!

Comment: Vlw Otavio sucesso no desenvolvimento.

Answer (score -1):

Você deve colocar o atributo name nos campos de input, na capitura do $_post['aqui você capitura o name do campo que colocou no ']; você vai capiturar o name que quer dentro das dos colchetes.